# Change content on drop down click

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, paypal

I am trying to make a paypal item with 2 drop down menus. I want to make it where the first drop down menu will change the second one depending on the choice. How should I go about doing this? I tried using javascript with onchange on the first menu and .innerHtml for the second.

```
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Year">Year</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="None">None </option><!-- Show list 1 -->
<option value="2015">2015 </option><!-- replace list 1 with list 2  -->
<option value="2016">2016 </option><!-- replace list 1 with list 2 -->
<option value="2017">2017 </option><!-- replace list 1 with list 2 -->
</select> </td></tr>


<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size">Size</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
<!-- List 1 -->
<option value="Youth X-Small">Youth X-Small </option>
<option value="Youth Medium">Youth Medium </option>
<option value="Youth Large">Youth Large </option>
<option value="Youth X-Large">Youth X-Large </option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small </option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium </option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large </option>
<option value="Adult X-Large">Adult X-Large </option>
<option value="Adult XX-Large">Adult XX-Large </option>
</select> </td></tr>

<!-- List 2 -->
<option value="Youth Large">Youth Large</option>
<option value="Youth X-Large">Youth X-Large</option>
<option value="Adult Small">Adult Small</option>
<option value="Adult Medium">Adult Medium</option>
<option value="Adult Large">Adult Large</option>
<option value="Adult X-Large">Adult X-Large</option>
<option value="Adult XX-Large">Adult XX-Large</option>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: yes got it .. use the function onchange using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery's change function

```
$("#idofselect").change(function(){ });
```